# How to Stop logging to console at startup of .net core app?

Tags: logging, .net-core

Something changed in my system configuration.
Every time I start dotnet application it spams a ton of log information to console.
Who knows what is it, and how to disable this kind of tracing?

It looks like a log from fuslogvw, but i checked it and it is disabled.

A start piece of log looks like this:

```
> dotnet My.dll
Tracing enabled @ Sun Dec  8 18:09:22 2019 GMT
--- Invoked dotnet [version: 3.0.0, commit hash: 7d57652f33493fa022125b7f63aad0d70c52d810] main = {
dotnet
My.dll
}
Reading fx resolver directory=[C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr]
Considering fxr version=[2.1.13]...
Considering fxr version=[3.0.0]...
Detected latest fxr version=[C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\3.0.0]...
Resolved fxr [C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\3.0.0\hostfxr.dll]...
Loaded library from C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\3.0.0\hostfxr.dll
Invoking fx resolver [C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\3.0.0\hostfxr.dll] v2
Host path: [C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe]
and so on...
```

UPDATE:
I created .net core default "Hello World" app with just one line of code

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

StartupLoggingDemo.deps.json

```
{
    "runtimeTarget": {
        "name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1",
        "signature": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709"
    },
    "compilationOptions": {},
    "targets": {
        ".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1": {
            "StartupLoggingDemo/1.0.0": {
                "runtime": {
                    "StartupLoggingDemo.dll": {}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "libraries": {
        "StartupLoggingDemo/1.0.0": {
          "type": "project",
          "serviceable": false,
          "sha512": ""
        }
    }
}
```

StartupLoggingDemo.runtimeconfig.dev.json

```
{
    "runtimeOptions": {
        "additionalProbingPaths": [
            "C:\\Users\\andre\\.dotnet\\store\\|arch|\\|tfm|",
            "C:\\Users\\andre\\.nuget\\packages",
            "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\NuGetFallbackFolder"
        ]
    }
}
```

StartupLoggingDemo.runtimeconfig.json

```
{
    "runtimeOptions": {
        "tfm": "netcoreapp2.1",
        "framework": {
            "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
            "version": "2.1.0"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: startup log output screenshot]
...

[image]

The text "Breadcrumbs will be written using a background thread" I found in [https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f9ae42d861fcb4be2fcd5d3d55d5f227d30e723/src/installer/corehost/cli/hostpolicy/breadcrumbs.cpp], but yet don't know, how to turn off the tracing.

Comment: Just to confirm you've already checked your config files including the.`dev` scoped file?

Comment: if you could post your appsetting.json and startup.cs and program.cs, we can see something if wrong.

Comment: Any app started with dotnet, loggs to console. Event those, which never did it before.

Answer (score 2):

I'v got an answer from @Vitek Karas MSFT.

The tracing is turned on by setting COREHOST_TRACE=1 (or any non-0). So make sure you’re running the app from an environment which doesn’t have this property set. (there’s no other way to enable it, only the environment variable).
Mode details can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f9ae42d861fcb4be2fcd5d3d55d5f227d30e723/docs/design/features/host-tracing.md